# Summary of errors in Parsley JS

Tags: parsley.js

Is it possible in Parsley validated fields to show the error not only by the field, but also as a summary at the bottom or top of the form? I've read over the documentation and examples and can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

see [the annotated source](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/defaults.html).

> Errors container #2.0
>   **data-parsley-errors-container="#element"**
>   Specify the existing DOM container where ParsleyUI should put the
>   errors. It is also possible to configure it with a callback function
>   from javascript, see the annotated source.